# Trying to plot clusters of vectorized file contents created with tf-idf in Python

Tags: python

I've been working on reading the contents of files, creating a vector and calculating the cosine similarity. I've got something that works and prints out the values, but I'm having an issue with trying to plot clusters with these results - here is the code I'm working with:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm


# Setup ps list
ps_list = []
ps_list_filename = []

# Walk directory and read each file into ps_list
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("<My Directory>"):
    
    for filename in filenames:
        with open("<My Directory>" + filename) as ps_file:
            if filename != ".DS_Store":
                ps_text = ps_file.read()

                ps_list.append(ps_text)
                ps_list_filename.append(filename)

with open("<My Directory>/ps6") as ps_testfile:
    ps_test_file = ps_testfile.read()
    


# Imports for tfidf, kmeans and plotting clusters
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


# Create searchable text data
text_data = np.array(ps_list)
print(type(text_data))

# Create the tf-idf feature matrix
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
feature_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(text_data)

# Transform ps_test_file
vector = tfidf.transform([ps_test_file])

# Calculate the cosine similarities
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(vector, feature_matrix).flatten()

# Get index of most relevant items in order
related_doc_indicies = cosine_sim.argsort()[:-10:-1]

# Print the most similar texts along with similarities
for ind, val in enumerate(text_data):
    print("Filename : {}".format(ps_list_filename[ind]))
    print("Similarity Score: {}\n".format(cosine_sim[ind]))



'''
Finding optimal clusters

'''


def find_optimal_clusters(data, max_k):
    iters = range(2, max_k+1, 2)
    
    sse = []
    
    for k in iters:
        sse.append(MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, init_size=1024, batch_size=2048, random_state=20).fit(data).inertia_)
        print("Fit {} clusters".format(k))
        
        f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        ax.plot(iters, sse, marker = 'o')
        ax.set_xlabel("Cluster Centers")
        ax.set_xticks(iters)
        ax.set_xticklabels(iters)
        ax.set_ylabel("SSE")
        ax.set_title("SSE by Cluster Center")
        
find_optimal_clusters(feature_matrix, 20)
```

This is an excerpt of what feature_matrix looks like

```
(0, 73857) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 19875) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 42871) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 32106) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 83268) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 38014) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 19251) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 70054) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 28092) 0.00593628548248403 
(0, 58485) 0.00593628548248403
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
builtins.ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
```

Any help would be appreciated.